# my example with ajax doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm trying to use ajax with a simple example, i took the example from : http://ocaoimh.ie/2008/11/01/make-your-wordpress-plugin-talk-ajax/ example N°5
(which doesn't work actually as it is)

So i'm trying just to get the result from the php page, located in /wp-content/ajax-php.php, but nothing, except the alert, seems to react. Could you have a look and tell me if you see something wrong? :

```
<?php
            /*
            Plugin Name: ajax with images
            Plugin URI: http://ocaoimh.ie/
            Description: A simple hello world plugin, taken from <a href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/jquery-getting-started.html#rate">here</a>
            Version: 0.1
            Author: Donncha O Caoimh
            Author URI: http://ocaoimh.ie/
            */

            function helloworld5_scripts() {
                    global $current_user;
                    if( !$current_user->ID )
                            return;
                    if( is_single() ) {
                            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
                    }
            }
            add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'helloworld5_scripts');

            function helloworld5_head() {
                    global $current_user;
                    if( !$current_user->ID )
                            return;
                    if( !is_single() )
                            return;
                    ?>
            <script  type='text/javascript'>
            <!--
            var currentpost = '';
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    // generate markup
                    var ratingMarkup = ["Please rate: "];
                    for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
                            ratingMarkup[ratingMarkup.length] = "<a href='#'>" + i + "du-texte-pour-tester</a> ";
                    }
                    // add markup to container and applier click handlers to anchors
                    jQuery("#rating").append( ratingMarkup.join('') ).find("a").click(function(e) {
                            //e.preventDefault();
                            // send requests
                            alert('ok');
                            jQuery.post("/wp-content/ajax-php.php", {rating: jQuery(this).html()}, function(data) {
                                    jQuery("#rating").append(data+' : hello ');
                            } );
                            return false;
                    });
            });
            // -->
            </script>
                    <?php
            }
            add_action( 'wp_head', 'helloworld5_head' );

            function add_thumb_to_post( $content ) {
                    global $post;
                    global $current_user;
                    if( !$current_user->ID )
                            return $content;
                    if( !is_single() )
                            return $content;
                    return $content . "<p><div id='rating'></div></p><script type='text/javascript'>\n<!--\ncurrentpost='{$post->ID}';\n//-->\n</script>";
            }
            add_action( 'the_content', 'add_thumb_to_post' );
            ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code is technically correct, though you should be doing ajax calls via the [WordPress provided means](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/how-to-make-ajax-call-in-wordpress-in-right-way). Also, your path to `ajax-php.php` will fail if WP isn't installed in root.

What does `ajax-php.php` contain and what are you expecting it to return? If you're trying to use WordPress functions inside of that file, you need to bootstrap WordPress by including `wp-load.php`. But again, you probably shouldn't be doing it that way in the first place, see the link above.

Comment: Also [Ajax in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) in Codex is a must read.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know how to use a basic code in the front-page, actually i understand this : http://cdn.ocaoimh.ie/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/helloworld4.txt which is to use Ajax in the admin area, but how should i do the same for a front-page? Simply add 'nopriv' ? the goal would be to click on "next" or "previous" and have the different post thumbnails in Ajax. Can you help me understand it?